# Java - Array JList, Print out a Value

Tags: java, jlist

I have a JList that is filled with an Array. I just want to print the value when the user selects something in the list and presses a button. I know it's something to do with getSelectedValues. When I searched online I got solutions to JLists filled with addItems but not when filled with an Array.

This is the code for the button at the moment:

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                Object[] selected = FilmList.getSelectedValues();
                String[] selectedItems = new String[selected.length];               
                System.out.println(selectedItems);

            }
```

The name of my JList is FilmList and the name of my array is films.
Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**
you should use 
`Object[] selected = FilmList.getSelectedValues(); System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(selected));`

**OR** If you want to store it in array of String you can do like this:

```
String[] selectedItems = new String[selected.length]; 
for (int i = 0 ; i < selectedItems.length ; i++)
{
 selectedItems[i] = (String)selected[i];
}
```

And then you can print the same as:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(selectedItems));
```

You can also print the values using for loop as:

```
for (int i =0; i < selectedItems.length ; i++)
System.out.println(selectedItems[i]));
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I just tried out your first suggestion, am I missing something? Because it's not liking '(selected)'.

Comment: can you explain the problem u getting by using my first suggestion?

Comment: @user2092012: that suggestion would work for JDK version 5.0 or above. If you using lower version then use the `for loop` that i had suggested in answer.

Comment: Selected is red and it says "selected cannot be resolved to a variable". Am I meant to create a variable called selected somewhere?

Comment: Yes you should define `selected` variable as you had written in your code in question. See my update.

Comment: That worked. Thanks a lot Vishal. I would vote your answers up if I could.

Comment: I tried voting it up but I need 15 reputation to be able to haha.

Answer (score 1):

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            Object[] selectedFilms = FilmList.getSelectedValues();
            for(int i = 0; i < selectedFilms.length; i++)
                System.out.print(selectedFilms[i].toString + ", ");
            System.out.println();
    }
```

May be you can do it shorter? Something like this?